# Regex finding processes in tasklist -v output in windows

Tags: python, regex, windows

I want to extract the process name pid username and windows title from the output of a `tasklist -v` command in windows. I used regex.

The output (part of it)

```
win32sysinfo.exe              4052 Services                   0      1.992 K Unknown         N/A                                                     0:00:00 N/A                                                                     
inet_gethost.exe              3264 Services                   0      4.740 K Unknown         N/A                                                     0:00:00 N/A                                                                     
taskhost.exe                  2564 Console                    1     18.940 K Running         domain\username                                      0:00:02 MCI command handling window
```

I am using regex and named groups in python

```
^(?P<pName>wininit\.exe)\s+(?P<pId>\d+)\s+(?P<sessionName>\w+)\s+(?P<sessionNum>\d+)\s+(?P<memoryUsage>\d+\.\d+\s+K)\s+(?P<status>\w+)\s+(?P<userName>\w+)\s+(?P<cpuTime>\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+(?P<windowTiitle>\w+)$
```

The problem is that the first 6 groups get matched correctly. But after 7th and forth it doesn't match correctly. It's because of the N/A and the domain\username fields. Any hints on the correct regex on that.

Comment: It would be a much better design to acquire this data programmatically than to parse the output of an external program. Check out the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/README.rst) library.

Comment: `^(?P<pName>wininit\.exe)` is certainly wrong, unless you only want to match `wininit.exe` (which is not in your sample input).

Comment: [tasklist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730909) supports CSV output via `/fo csv`. You can parse this using Python's `csv` module, e.g. `tasks = list(csv.DictReader(subprocess.check_output("tasklist /v /fo csv", universal_newlines=True).splitlines()))`. Each item is the info for a running process as a dict with keys such as "User Name", "Session Name", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `\w+` for both user name and window title - but both may contain other characters as well.

For the user name, `\S+` (non-space characters) may work well. For the window title, since it is the last group, you may want to use just `.+` to match anything until the end.